# Phone not showing in Finder (but available for Dropbox)

Tags: finder, usb, mount

I use a 3-years old Nokia X2-01 phone and moved to the Mac recently. I'd like to copy some files to the phone but I do not see it in the Finder.

In Windows, I used to be able to plug the phone in via USB and be able to access the phone's internal memory.

The phone is recognized by the system to that extent:
- In System Report > USB: the phone is listed as X2-01.
- When I plugged the phone in the first time, Dropbox askd me if I wanted to import the pictures on the phone. Saying yes, the pictures were successfully copied from the phone to my Dropbox folder.

Using `diskutil list`, the phone is not listed among the drives there. Is this the place to look at for a USB drive?

I only care about copying files to the phone. It's not a big deal if I can't do it from the Finder, being able to do so from the command-line would be enough.

Comment: Did you try changing the USB mode in `Menu > Settings > Connectivity > USB data cable`? It's strange that Dropbox is able to recognise the phone, while it doesn't show in Finder.

Comment: I do have 3 options there (Nokia Ovi suite; Media transfer; Mass storage) but none of them got the phone to show up in Finder. The second one would be the appropriate one (that's the one that got Dropbox to offer me to copy pictures *from* the phone.)

Comment: I've a Nokia 6300 and when I use the Media transfer option Image capture shows up (I don't have Dropbox), but I can't find a way to copy file *to* my phone either. However, the Mass storage option mounts my phone's *memory card* as a disk on the desktop. I can't copy files to the internal memory through USB.

Comment: I think you've several options: 1) copy to the memory card, then on the phone move the file to the internal memory; 2) send the file through Bluetooth; 3) See if programs like [SyncMate](http://mac.eltima.com/sync_mac_mtp.html) or [Android File Manager](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) work for you.

Comment: Completely forgot about Bluetooth... That did the trick, thank you. I'll keep the question open for the USB side of things.